# debian 10 microphone not working on browser

Tags: debian, ubuntu, firefox, chrome, browser

In browsers like firefox, chromium, etc microphone not working,
but in the conference app like zoom microphone works well,
what to do to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide more information on your system? Like if you are using alsa or jack or pulseaudio.

Comment: pulseaudio, analog stereo duplex